# Are these sets the same $\{x\in \mathbb{R}:0\le x\le1\}$ and $\{0\le x\le1:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

In Guide to Analysis by Hart in example 1.4.1 she's using two notations to express the sets

$S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:0\le x\le1\}$

and

$S=\{{1\over n}: n\in \mathbb{Z^+}\}$

Does it make a difference if I define a set and specify domain first or last? What is the convention?

In short: is $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}:0\le x\le1\} =\{0\le x\le1:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: Your second one (in the title) is strange. Just read it out: first is "set of all real $x$ such that $x$ between $0$ and $1$", the second would be "set of $x$ between 0 and 1 such that $x$ is real". This is odd phrasing because $0\leq x\leq 1$ implies $x$ real in the first place. Of course, a reader will still be able to understand what you mean. As for $\{1/n : n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$, again, reverse it, read it out, it will not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{\,0\le x\le 1:x\in\Bbb R\,\}$ does not match any common notation pattern for sets. Here's a list of the most common notation patterns for sets:

- $\emptyset$ or $\{\}$ for the empty set, the set without elements.
- $\{a,b\}$ for the set whose elements are $a$ and $b$ and nothing else. More precisely, $x$ is an element of this set if and only if the statement $x=a\lor x=b$ is true. This notation is motivated and justified by the Pairing Axiom of set theory, which precisely states this: If $a,b$ are sets, then there exists a set $c$ such that $x\in c\leftrightarrow x=a\lor x=b$ holds. Note that it is not required that $a\ne b$, though for that special case, we would conventionally use the notation $\{a\}$. Formally, $\{a\}:=\{a,a\}$. Likewise, for any finite list $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$, it is common to use the similar notation $\{a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n\}$ for the set having precisely $a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n$ as elements (though preferably, this should please be used only when no ambiguous "$\ldots$" are actually used).
- $\{\,x\in a:\phi(x)\,\}$, where $a$ is a set and $\phi$ is a predicate. This is used for the set for which $x$ is an element if and only if $x\in a$ and $\phi(x)$ holds. The notation is motivated and justified by the Axiom Schema of Comprehension, which states exactly that such a set exists for all given $a$ and $\phi$.
- $\{\,F(x):x\in a\,\}$, where $a$ is a set and $F$ is a (class) function. This is used for the set for which $y$ is an element if and only there exists an $x\in a$ such that $y=F(x)$. The notation is motivated and justified by the Axiom Schema of Replacement, which states exactly that such a set exists for all given $a$ and $F$.
- finally, expressions in sets, such as $a\cap b$, $a\setminus b$, $\bigcup a$ and so on.

Note that $\{\,x\in \mathbb{R}:0\le x\le1\,\}$ is an example of the third kind and $\{\,{1\over n}: n\in \mathbb{Z^+}\,\}$ is of the fourth kind (and could be turned in to third kind e.g. as $\{\,x\in\Bbb Q:\exists n\in\Bbb Z^+, x=\frac1n\,\}$ by observing that the reciprocals are all rational.

However, $\{0\le x\le1:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ does not match the above and so could easily lead to confusion. E.g., one might think you wanted to refer to the set of all possible truth values the predicate $0\le x\le 1$ can assume if $x$ runs over all elements of $\Bbb R$, so that would be $\{\text{true},\text{false}\}$.

Finally, let me add that a variation of the set builder notation of the third kind, $\{\,x:\phi(x)\,\}$ is known as class-builder notation. So this is a well-established notation and *could* stand for a set, but a priori stands for a possibly proper class. In this respect, the notation is at least sloppy when intended to actually stand for a set. The more formal notations listed above "guarantee" to stand for sets and without leaving the reader to guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Whichever way you write it, your meaning will be understood. The more usual way of writing it (in my experience, at least) is to define a set like
$$\{ x: p(x)\}$$
where $p(x)$ is a proposition which $x$ must satisfy (maybe it is $x^2=1$, or $|x|\leq 1$, or whatever). If we wanted to specify the set we're working in, one usually writes
$$\{ x\in S: p(x)\}$$
where, of course, $S$ is the set we are working in. It is extremely unusual to write it the other way around like $\{p(x):x\in S\}$, but of course it wouldn't technically be wrong; it's just a matter of convention. The reason the order is usually taken to be in this way is because it makes more sense when read out. It's smoother to say for example "the set of all $x$ in $S$ so that $p(x)$ is true" rather than "under the condition $p(x)$, the set of all $x$ in $S$".

Answer (score 0):

They are the same: in both cases you get the set of all real numbers $x$ between (and including) $0$ and $1$

But the first notation is more common .. with this kind of set builder notation, you typically want to express "all the objects from [some set] such that [some property holds]". That is, first you want to make clear what the 'Universe of Discourse' is, i.e. what kinds of objects you want to talk about, and then you want to indicate which of those you want. The first notation naturally follows that format.